# Child is Unable to inherit Index

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, getproperties

Updated the code..

```
public class UpdateProductTemplate
{
    [Index(0)]
    public string ProductID { get; set; }
    [Index(2)]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    [Index(3)]
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
}

public class UpdateProductTemplateWithPrice: UpdateProductTemplate
{
    // For PRICE Updates!
    [Index(4)]
    public double? SitePrice { get; set; }
    [Index(5)]
    public double? ListPrice { get; set; }
    [Index(6)]
    public double? WebSitePrice { get; set; }
}


List<UpdateProductTemplateWithPrice> Products = new List<UpdateProductTemplateWithPrice>() {
            new UpdateProductTemplateWithPrice
            {
                ProductID = "123",
                ProductName = "Test Product",
                ShortDescription = "Test",
                SitePrice = 123.00,
                ListPrice = 123.00,
                WebSitePrice = 123.00
            }
        };

Type type = products.ToArray()[0].GetType();

PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
{
    var cell = headerRow.CreateCell(i);
    cell.SetCellValue(properties[i].Name);
}
```

When I do `GetProperties()`, it ends up with the `SitePrice` first on the array. I don't want that I want `ProductID` to be first in the properties array...

I already did placed a higher index value in the child class, and expected `ProductID` to be first when I do `GetProperties()`, but it didn't.

Comment: Exactly what `IndexAttribute` is that that you have applied to those properties? I suspect that it doesn't actually do what you think it does.

Comment: *"Sorry I was unable to copy the part where I populate the products"*. You don;t necessarily need to copy exactly what you have in your project. You do need to provide the simplest example you can that demonstrates your actual issue. I would expect that you could provide code that adds a single item to the list with the same or similar values to what you're actually using.

Comment: @jmcilhinney sorry about that. I've edited the code and updated the post. :) I just want the child class to spit out the "ProductID" first when I do the GetProperties().

Comment: Can you answer my first question? I want to confirm what that attribute is and what it does before answering.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Well I was hoping for the Index attribute to help me sort out the Properties when I do GetProperties()? Don't know really if I'm doing it correctly or not. Sorry :'(

Comment: Do not use inheritance. Use composition. And your problem goes away.

Comment: For the third time, please answer the question. What is that attribute? I understand what you were hoping it would do. I understood that from the start. I'm asking you what type it is, i.e. the fully qualified name of the class.

Comment: @MortenBork, the immediate problem may go away but another problem will appear in its place. Also, it looks like inheritance is the correct choice based on the actual relationship between the types, i.e. "Is a" rather than "has a".

Comment: @jmcilhinney
Inheritence is never the right choice, you will always end up with exponential unit-test count (If you have test coverage) It is much harder to extend your code base if you have used inheritance, as opposed to composition. As a default you should ALWAYS chose composition over inheritance. It methodology provides more flexible and durable codebase. Composition is superior in all aspects. In fact, I cannot think of a single scenario where I would deliberately pick inheritance. (Not just this specific question)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:
Install package `Newtonsoft.Json`

```
    public class UpdateProductTemplate
    {
        [JsonPropertyOrder(0)]
        public string ProductID { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyOrder(1)]
        public int CompanyID { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyOrder(2)]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyOrder(3)]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class UpdateProductTemplateWithPrice : UpdateProductTemplate
    {
        // For PRICE Updates!
        [JsonPropertyOrder(4)]
        public double? SitePrice { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyOrder(5)]
        public double? ListPrice { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyOrder(6)]
        public double? WebSitePrice { get; set; }
    }
```

```
List<UpdateProductTemplateWithPrice> Products = new List<UpdateProductTemplateWithPrice>() {
            new UpdateProductTemplateWithPrice
            {
                ProductID = "123",
                ProductName = "Test Product",
                ShortDescription = "Test",
                SitePrice = 123.00,
                ListPrice = 123.00,
                WebSitePrice = 123.00
            }
        };

var product = Products[0];

var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(product,
    new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true }
);
Console.WriteLine(json);

var jsonData = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (var item in jsonData)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
}
```

OutPut
[image]

Comment: What worked is if I used string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ProductsToUpdate, Formatting.Indented) and also used [JsonProperty(Order = -2)]

Answer (score 0):

based on the question and sample, created a simple Index attribute as below.

```
public class Index : Attribute
{            
    public Index(int index) { _index = index; }

    private int _index;
    public int Value { get { return _index; } }
}
```

I think the simplest answer would be to call the Sort method with a custom comparer. Like this:

```
 List<PropertyInfo> properties = new List<PropertyInfo>(typeof(UpdateProductTemplateWithPrice).GetProperties());

        properties.Sort((PropertyInfo a, PropertyInfo b) =>
        {
            Index indexA = a.GetCustomAttribute<Index>();
            Index indexB = b.GetCustomAttribute<Index>();

            if ((indexA is null) || (indexB is null))
                return 0;

            if (indexA.Value > indexB.Value)
                return 1;
            if (indexA.Value < indexB.Value)
                return -1;
            if (indexA.Value == indexB.Value)
                return 0;

            return 0;
        });
```

That will return the properties in the expected order.